# Getting an Uniform Type Identifier for a given extension in iOS

Tags: ios, file, uti

I'm trying to find some way to get extension of a file from its UTI in iOS.

to get file extension from any UTIs like

"public.jpeg"

"public.html"

"com.adobe.pdf"

Any methods like "preferredFilenameExtensionForType" of NSWorkspace in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

```
let ext = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(kUTTypeGIF, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension)?.takeRetainedValue()
```